# AngularJS: how can I pass data to a tooltip without having to put in a character with the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tooltip

I am using [Angular Tooltips by 702kb - GitHub](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips) and I am trying to pass some data to my tooltip like this:

```
<div class="ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-min" ng-controller="HRAController">
    <a tooltips tooltip-html="{{ data.pressureHigh }} / {{ data.pressureLow }}" tooltip-show-trigger="mouseover click" tooltip-hide-trigger="click" tooltip-side="top" tooltip-scroll="true" class="custom-tooltip">&nbsp;</a>
</div>

<div class="ngrs-handle ngrs-handle-max" ng-controller="HRAController">
    <a tooltips tooltip-html="{{ data.cholesterol }}" tooltip-show-trigger="mouseover click" tooltip-hide-trigger="click" tooltip-side="top" tooltip-scroll="true" class="custom-tooltip">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

The first one, `{{ data.pressureHigh }} / {{ data.pressureLow }}`, works fine because of the "/". This is simply coincidence because I actually need the "/" in there.

The second one, `{{ data.cholesterol }}`, gives an empty tooltip (tooltip doesn't show up at all because it thinks theres nothing in it), but if I were to add a character, such as adding a percentage after the data, like `{{ data.cholesterol }}%`, then the tooltip would show up and show the data now with a trailing "%". The problem is there shouldn't be any trailing characters so this is giving me trouble.

Is there any way I can put in just the data and not be required to have a character in there with it for the data to be properly outputted?

I tried using both `tooltip-html=""` and `tooltip-content=""` (both can be seen on the GitHub link above) but both have the same functionality as far as my problem goes.

Comment: instead of a a `%` you can try a `&nbsp;`? What does it do without the `{{ }}`? Since it's a directive, you shouldn't need the curly braces

Comment: Please publish the full source (include your JS).

Comment: Roy Miloh the source is far too large to post here. Ronnie I tried $nbsp; good idea, but it doesn't work. If I don't put a {{ }} and just leave a space, basically the same thing happens and it doesn't show the tooltip because it thinks nothing is there. If I likewise ignore the {{ }} and just put some regular text, it will show the tooltip with the text.